# Logcat color changed to be Yellow in Jelly Beans

Tags: android, logcat, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have updated my Google galaxy Nexus (4.0.3 ICS) to Jelly Bean ( offical update thru updates notification on phone).
After updating, my logcat only gives me yellow text ( for all warning, verbose, debug, or error logcat mode).
This is really annoying when you got to many messages to filter.
The filter function on logcat is also disabled.

Did anyone meet this problem, how to solve that? 
Thank you for your reading.

Comment: don't know why I got a minus :-? It's a question and I have no answer , so I ask and I give a description. How come could I receive a minus ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should update the `ADT`. After this all will be as usual